# Carregando ID da Sessão

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela contendo id do usuário, email, senha e classificação (admin ou não). Quando a pessoa faz login, estou fazendo com que carregue para outras sessões já que o sistema introduz despesas em um banco de dados e tem que estar associado a cada pessoa. Quando tento carregar o id do usuário, estou tendo problemas, dizendo que o segundo "row" está indefinido. Como isso ocorre se meu primeiro row funcionou? Como posso solucionar?
Deixei também o segundo código da área de despesas, onde estou tendo problemas para pegar o id do usuário e jogar junto com a despesa.

Edit: esqueci de salientar que, muitos casos aqui no stack se relacionam com a função de id já existente (para cada conexão). Neste caso que coloco aqui, é o id que eu mesmo coloquei para cada usuário no banco de dados.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
        $erros = array();
        $username = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['senha']);

        if(empty($username) or empty($password)):
            $erros[] = "<li>Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos.</li>";
        else:
            $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0):
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                if ($dados['admin'] == '1'):
                    mysqli_close($connect);
                    $id_user = $_REQUEST['id_user'];
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $password;
                    $_SESSION['id_user'] =$row['id_user'];  
                    header('Location: areaAdm.php');

                else:
                     mysqli_close($connect);
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $password;
                    $_SESSION['id_user'] = $row['id_user'];  
                    header('Location: areaUsuario.php');
                endif;
```

```
<?php
session_start();
include('classes/db_connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//definindo todas as variáveis para preencher a tabela

//sessao do usuario
$id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

//definindo formato do arquivo
$extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['fotoDespesa']['name'], -4));
$novo_nome = md5(time()). $extensao;
$diretorio = "uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoDespesa']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

//destino da despesa
$tipoReembolso= $_POST['tipoReembolso'];

//tipo da despesa
$type=$_POST['tipoDespesa'];

//data formatada para dia-mes-ano)
$olddate=$_POST['data'];
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($olddate));

//quilometragem (se for o caso)
$km =$_POST['numeroKm'];

//preço despesa
$price=$_POST['precoDespesa'];

//mensagem de observação
$message=$_POST['observacao'];

    $insert="INSERT INTO despesas(
      id_user, 
      tipoDespesa, 
      dataDespesa, 
      precoDespesa, 
      fotoDespesa, 
      tipoReembolso,
      observacao)
    VALUES(
      '$id_user',
      '$type',
      '$date', 
      '$price',
      '$novo_nome',
      '$tipoReembolso',
      '$message')";
    if(mysqli_query($connect,$insert)){

    echo "Sucesso ao enviar a despesa!";
    }
    else {
    echo "Erro ao enviar! Por favor, preencha todos os campos.";
    }
}

?>
```

O erro no segundo caso, relacionada a sessão do id_user e eu creio que esteja ligada a página de login.

Comment: O correto não seria $dados['id_user']; ? veja $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

Answer (score 0):

Cara tem duas percepções que vi no código que você postou. Uma delas é na sua query de inserção você coloca `'$id_user'` (com aspas) verifique se é realmente uma string que você deve passar, se não for remova as aspas. Outro ponto é o seu `include('classes/db_connect.php');` já instância sua conexão?